# Need to validate a calendar application against invalid dates

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, java

I am testing a calendar application, which allows a user to select `day`, `month` and `year`, but the problem is the developers have not implemented any form of date validations, which means every month can have up to 31 days.

- The `year` dropdown menu has a range from 1900 to 2016,
- the `month` dropdown menu has Jan, Feb ... Dec,
- the `day` dropdown menu always has 1~31, regardless of which month I choose.

The testing strategy I am thinking of is:

- choose one non-leap year and test against `29th Feb`; expected to **fail**
- choose one non-leap year and test against `31st April`; expected to **fail**
- choose one leap year and test against `29th Feb`; expected to **succeed**
- choose one leap year and test against `31st April`; expected to **fail**

Four scenarios above should provide a good coverage regarding leap years.

What are your opinions? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to

- choose one non-leap year and test against 29th Feb; expected to fail
- choose one non-leap year and test against 31st April; expected to fail
- choose one leap year and test against 29th Feb; expected to succeed
- choose one leap year and test against 31st April; expected to fail

I would consider adding more positive tests at day (time), month and year boundaries:

- choose one non-leap year and test against 01 Jan; expected to pass
- choose one non-leap year and test against 31 Dec; expected to pass
- choose one non-leap year and test against 28th Feb; expected to pass
- choose one leap year and test against 28th Feb; expected to pass
- choose one non-leap year and test against 1st Mar; expected to pass
- choose one non-leap year and test against 1st Feb; expected to pass
- choose one non-leap year and test against 1st May; expected to pass
- choose one non-leap year and test against 30th June; expected to pass
- choose a time that is in the next or previous day GMT-wise and test at that time; expected to pass

Comment: Nice, nice nice. Will add more boundary tests. Thank you. @Michael Durrant